# Pyspark - window.PartitionBy() - Number of partitions

Tags: pyspark, partitioning

I am using PySpark v1.6.2 and my code goes like this:

```py
df = sqlContext.sql('SELECT * FROM <lib>.<table>')
df.rdd.numPartitions() ## 2496
df = df.withColumns('count', lit(1)) ## up to this point it still has 2496 partitions
df = df.repartition(2496,'trip_id').sortWithinPartitions('trip_id','time')
# This is where the trouble starts
sequenceWS = Window.partitionBy('trip_id').orderBy('trip_id','time') ## Defining a window
df = df.withColumn('delta_time', (df['time'] - min(df['time']).over(sequenceWS.rowsBetween(-1, 0))))
# Done with window function
df.rdd.numPartitions() ## 200
```

**My question is:**

Is there a way to tell pyspark how many partitions it should make when using the function `Window.partionBy(*cols)`?

Alternatively, is there a way to influence `PySpark` as to keep the same number of partitions as it had before the window function is applied on its DataFrame?

Comment: It's a hack, and doesn't do exactly what you want, but "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" controls the default number of partitions *globally*, so it can change the "200" to whatever you want (except it would affect all other 200s in your job as well)